# Как на Android подменить GPS без перевода в режим Mock?

Tags: android

Есть такое приложение на андройде как Zelle.
Оно не дает произвести действие, если GPS в режиме MOCK.
Пишет, что проблема при определении локации. По видимо оно как то определяет состояние GPS устройства.

Я получил полный root доступ к устройству и его shell. Может есть какие то способы подмены GPS на уровне ниже ?

Android 5.0.1
Samsung S4 GT-I9500

Answer (score 2):

Есть приложения спуферы GPS, поищите в Play Market с ключевыми словами [Fake GPS](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=fake%20gps&c=apps&hl=en_US&gl=US).

Смысл очень простой. Устанавливаете спуфер, выбираете какую GPS координату она будет подсовывать, запускаете приложение и все, любой запрос на получение GPS координат будет подменен спуфером.

Comment: Я уже использовал эти приложения ранее. Для того что бы их активировать нужно либо включать Mock режим либо указывать, в разделе для разработчиков, программу для подмены GPS. Но приложение все это определяет, что была произведена подмена GPS и выдает ошибку, что не может определить местоположение.